# Using navigation property of OData in SAPUI5 XML view

Tags: odata, sapui5

Assume there are two entity tables namely Customer and Order with following fields:
Customer-> Id, CustomerName, OrderId
Order-> Id, CustomerId, OrderName

Now in Odata service, following association as well as navigation property is also defined i.e.

```
"Customers" navigates ("Customer_Orders" as "HisOrders");
association "Customer_Orders" principal "Customers"("ID") multiplicity "1"
dependent "Orders"("CustomerID") multiplicity "*";
```

In webapp, myview.xml there exists a table that has 3 columns: CustomerId, CustomerName, OrderName.

I added the binding for rows as `items={/Customers}`
For columns CustomerId and CustomerName, i used following: `{CustomerId} and {CustomerName}`

But how to bind OrderName column in the xml view itself?

Comment: You can't bind `OrderName` in a single text property due to the *\*- multiplicity* (One customer has many orders). When the binding is resolved, you'll get an array instead of a primitive value. What you can do, however, is to display (or navigate to) a separate table that shows only orders related to the selected customer (via navigation property) once a row is clicked from the customer table.

Answer (score 2):

Try this way:

```
<Label text="Order ID"/>
<Text text="{OrderID}" objectBindings="{Customer_Orders}" />
```

Here I assume `"Customer_Orders"` is the NavigationProperty's name and `"OrderID"` is the navigate target's property.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use an OData $expand to get the Order entity along with the Customer. I assume that your Entity Sets are called 'Customers' and 'Orders' (it would usually be CustomerSet and OrderSet).

In an XMLView you should do sth. like this:

```
<Table items="{
         path: '/Customers',
         parameters: {
           expand: 'Orders'
         }
       }">
```

Then your columns binding goes like:

```
{Orders/OrderName}
```

I must admit that I haven't done this for a 1:1 relationship but it should basically work like this. Please post your code and metadata.xml if it still does not work.

BR
Chris